# More [GET] request-response examples with different URI parameters

Tags: parameters, apiblueprint, blueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I have an URI: /lessons/{language}/{type}

I would like to have more mock requests-responses with different parameters {language} and {type} in my blueprint. It seems to me that this is not possible for GET method.

My idea is that: GET /lessons/cs/easy would return:

```
    [{
      "id": 1, "title": "Střední řada: s, l"
    }, {
      "id": 2, "title": "Střední řada: g, h"
    }]
```

And GET /lessons/de/easy would return:

```
    [{
      "id": 1, "title": "Mittle words: s, l"
    }, {
      "id": 2, "title": "Mittle words: g, h"
    }]
```

This is my syntax (down below) which is not working.

[image: This syntax not working. I would like to have something like this]

This is how it looks like in preview.
[image: This is how it looks like in preview.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with API Blueprint. But we have a feature request about this at https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/58 and we are planning to implement this very soon.

Thanks.